# Как записать данные в двумерный массив, чтобы не вводить каждый элемент по отдельности с#

Tags: c#

Необходимо ввести значения в двумерный массив с большим количеством строк и столбцов. Нужно чтобы ввод осуществлялся в строку через пробел и каждый элемент присваивался своему значению, только на реализацию подобной идеи не хватает ни мозгов, ни терпения.

> Например: инициализировали массив 3 строки 2 столбца
>
> Ввод: `10 20 30 40 50 60`
> Вывод 
> 10 20
> 30 40
> 50 60

```
        Console.WriteLine("Enter the number of pairs");
        int column = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine()); //столбцы 
        int row = 2; //строки 
        int[,] mas = new int[column, row];
        string[] str_arr;
        
            for (int i = 0; i < column; ++i)
        {
            str_arr = (Console.ReadLine()).Split(' ');
            for (int j =0; j<row ;j++)
            Console.WriteLine("{0} {1} {2}",i,j,str_arr[j]);
               mas[i, j] = Convert.ToInt32(str_arr[j]);
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ну принцип, наверное, правильный, только вы напутали много чего. Без проверки количества элементов будет примерно так:

```
 Console.WriteLine("Enter the number of pairs");
 int rows = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine()); //строки
 int columns = 2; //столбцы
 int[,] mas = new int[rows, columns];
 string[] str_arr;

 int k = 0;

 //ввод строки до цикла
 //если строк будет много (из примера непонятно), понадобится ещё цикл
 str_arr = (Console.ReadLine()).Split(' ');

 for (int i = 0; i < rows; ++i)
    {
        for (int j =0; j<columns ;j++) {
           Console.WriteLine("{0} {1} {2}",i,j,str_arr[k]);
           mas[i, j] = Convert.ToInt32(str_arr[k]);
           k++;
         }
    }
```

Comment: `.Split(' ')` можно как просто `.Split()`.

Comment: @MBo, не знаете как вывести матрицу? при переходе на новую строку выдает исключение Unhandled exception. System.IndexOutOfRangeException: Index was outside the bounds of the array.

Comment: @MBo, https://wampi.ru/image/REwhUIi ссылка на ошибку

Comment: Вы опять перепутали строки и столбцы. Надо i<rows,    j<columns.

Comment: @MBo, спасибо большое!